# MySQL error : Access denied for user (using password:NO) - python

Tags: python, mysql, flask, localhost, access-denied

I am new to MySQL , i am trying to make a simple registration form using MySQL database and python with FLask as severside framework .

I got the following error when running code in localhost :
[image]

> MySQL configuration :

```
app.config['MySQL_HOST'] ='localhost'
app.config['MySQL_USER'] = 'blacksmith'
app.config['MySQL_PASSWORD'] = '123456'
app.config['MySQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MySQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
```

> register function with route

```
@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST']) #route accepts get request per default but we precise here post also
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate(): # check if form is validated and its a post request
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username= form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

        #create cursor
        cur =mysql.connection.cursor()

        # execute SQL command
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name,email,username,password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,email,username,password) )

        #commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #close connection
        cur.close()

    return render_template('register.htm',form=form)
```

I got the same error ( **Access denied for user root@localhost** ) also when i access MySQL shell in my bash shell using the command

```
mysql -u root
```

( i had to use **sudo command** to access the database )

The problem that i didn't set **any password** for MySQL database access , and the same error persists even when trying to change it with another password using the command :

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'newPass';
```

I tried also to change password in MySQL configuration with no success .

**I am stuck with that any help please !**

Comment: Hi :)
Have you tried to do it?
[B.4.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: check the grants for that user

Comment: @Bukse thanks but that didn't help : Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root@localhost'

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by running mysql server in safe mode :

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
service mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

if you encounter ( mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists. ) error

```
 mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
 chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

- the server works now in safe mode , open a new bash command and execute

  mysql -u root

that should work normally

Answer (score -1):

"Using password: NO". So wherever you are creating a connection, you aren't using a password.

Comment: Then why is the access denied , what's wrong with that ?

Comment: you have `MySQL_PASSWORD` set in your configuraiton. The error message shows its not being used.  Look at where `mysql.connection` is made and see if it actually uses the password.

Comment: @danblack Dude, don't do that, Just don't.

Comment: hmm. No "do" instructions where issued, just look at how it is. Answer could have been better, but probably too later now. Considering the other answer of run without any authentication barriers ...